# UPDATE таблицы, учитывая текущее значение

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица, в которой большое количество строк. Примерная структура:

```
id(int) | group_id(int) | arrays(TEXT)
```

Один из столбцов - это идентификатор группы. Мне нужно выполнить UPDATE ко всем строкам определенной группы, но не полностью изменить значение, а добавив новое к старому. Вот псевдопример требуемого запроса запроса.

```
UPDATE table SET arrays='текущее_значение_поля'+'Новое_значение_поля' WHERE group_id=13;
```

В данный момент я реализовал это через SELECT ко всем строкам, у которых group_id = 13, и в цикле перебора результатов делаю UPDATE каждой строке. На демо - данных работает, но в рабочей базе количество строк для группы может исчисляться тысячами.

Есть ли какой - нибудь способ это сделать одним \ двумя запросами?

**UPD** - СУБД MySQL

Comment: СУБД у вас какая?

Comment: СУБД у меня MySQL.

Comment: _новое_значнеие_поле_ это не постоянная величина и зависит как то от id или старого значения? или в чем проблема то вообще?

Comment: @teran, проблема в том, что я не знал, что в теле запроса UPDATE можно получить текущее значение строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET arrays=CONCAT(arrays, 'Новое_значение_поля') WHERE group_id=13;
```

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev и что из этого следует?

Comment: @teran что я привык к постгресу, где конкатенация делается не функцией, а оператором. Мой косяк.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, concat(str "any" [, str "any" [, ...] ]) в PG тоже прекрасно работает https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/functions-string

Comment: У меня та же проблема только мне надо не просто добавить, а и в случае если значение уже есть в ячейке не писать его повторно, выглядит это так:

Comment: [1][22][44] + строка '[44][33][555]' как сделать чтоб в ячейку добавилось только [33][555] без повторяющегося [44] ?